# Filter word starting with /

Tags: java, php, html, mysql

Great question system here!

I need help, I am a noob with coding, just so you know.

I have a panel (php, html, java and mysql).
This panel extracts info from a mysql server and displays it.
This info is mainly commands.

I don't want it to show these commands
-/login passwordhere
-/register passwordhere
-/changepassword passwordhere

Is there any filter I can add to a script?
Could someone make me a very simple script? I will keep the credits in the script!

Thank you so much in advance!

Very Best Regards.

Comment: Could we get the code of your "panel"?

Comment: Use like query LIKE '/%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
  SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '/', -1) AS foo FROM Table1;
```

look [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21d804/1)

Answer (score 0):

Something like `SELECT my_field FROM my_table WHERE my_field LIKE '/%'`

`%` is a wildcard in LIKE patterns, so this filters for rows whose `my_field` starts with `/` and then countians anything else. It's like a Java/php regexp of `/.*`.